# Latex: Text cannot be placed below image

Tags: layout, latex, figure, text-alignment

I'm having a problem with an image and some text. I have this code:

```
Some text...\\

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{picture.jpg}
\caption{The caption}   
\label{fig:picture}
\end{figure}

Some more text...
```

Basically, I want this:

```
Some text. (Above image in the code)
[end of page / new page]
image
Some more text. (Below the image in the code)
[start of new section]
```

But, what the above code gives me is this:

```
Some text. (Above image in the code)
Some more text. (Below the image in the code)
[end of page / new page]
image
[start of new section]
```

Latex insists on putting everything but a new section above the image even though its below the image in the code. Its probably because the image floats on top - but whats my alternative? There's not enough space on the first page to display the image there, to I cannot use [h] as the float-alignment.

I can "hack it", by creating an empty new section, like `\section*{}`, but this creates some white-space, which looks weird. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you really need to do that? I mean, LaTeX is great in managing float and cross-references, being one of its main features to achieve a beautiful typesetting and a nice page layout...

Comment: This is off topic. Should be trasferred to TEX Exchange ASAP

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If you *really* need to have the figure in that place, use the `float` package:

In the preamble:

```
\usepackage{float}
```

then, in the text:

```
Some text...

\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.75]{picture.jpg}
  \caption{The caption}   
  \label{fig:picture}
\end{figure}

Some more text...
```

Even though, is more preferable to let LaTeX place the floats.

---

Another way to do the same thing is by using the `caption` package.

In the preamble:

```
\usepackage{caption}
```

then, in the text:

```
Some text...

\begin{center}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.75]{picture.jpg}
  \captionof{figure}[LOF entry]{The caption}   
  \label{fig:picture}
\end{center}

Some more text...
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! How do I let latex place the floats? If I dont add the [ht] or whatever float I want, it just places the image at the end of my document.

Am I placing the image in a weird place? Where would you place it?

Comment: use preferably two placing options: [tb] for small figures, that stay well with the text on a single page; otherwise, for large figures, use [p].
More control on floats placement can be achieved with the package placeins

Comment: Cool, I didnt know about those. [tb] seems to place the image exactly where it logically should be placed, so that seems to be exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score -1):

Use captionof instead of caption:
\usepackage{caption}

```
Some text...

\begin{center}
  \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{picture.jpg}
  \captionof{figure}{Caption contents}  
  \label{fig:picture}
\end{center}

Some more text...
```